# Recommendations on how to save data in VB.Net?

Tags: database, vb.net, persistence, basic

I'm learning Visual Basic in Visual Studio (Community 2015) at the moment and currently developing a system to store data (names, phone numbers, Emails ect) This data is persistent of course but does not require a connection to an external database.

For example I have a directory to store the data to ProgramDirectory\records\ 
I feel that there must be a better way to store data than in a plain text .txt

Does anybody have any recommendations for methods and implementations?

Comment: I'm sure you will be scolded for not posting your code so far. And/or asking too broad a question... That said one approach is outlined below using a XML file and a DataTable.

Comment: a) database; b) List(of Contact) serialized to xml or c) json or d) binary file

Answer (score 0):

You are on one possible track with the Persistence tag.

Here is a snippet to create and XML file and then load the XML file. When you place the code in VS you'll see the "create" statements for a datatable are commented out. When un-commented, an executed, they create an empty table that can later be loaded and edited. (You need to supply a valid file path for `INI_FILE_C` in the code.) Comment out the create statements once you have a XML file to work with.

```
        ' load from XML file
        dt = New DataTable("MyTable")
        ' the following .Add() statements are not needed after the initial WriteXML - creates XML file with schema
        'dt.Columns.Add("Active", GetType(Boolean))
        'dt.Columns.Add("Profile")
        'dt.Columns.Add("Initials")
        'dt.Columns.Add("SQLServer")
        'dt.Columns.Add("SQLDatabase")
        'dt.WriteXml(INI_FILE_C, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema)

        dt.ReadXml(INI_FILE_C)

        dgv2.DataSource = dt
        dgv2.AutoResizeColumns()
        dgv2.ClearSelection()
```

Later to save the data from the DataGridView:

```
        dt.WriteXml(INI_FILE_C, XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema)
```

Comment: Great I'll conduct some research into XML data tables, just one question before I get started, what should i define "dt" and dgv2 as? Or am I just missing an import? (As said above I am completely new to this)

Comment: dt is a `DataTable` and dgv2 is a `DataGridview` control on a WinForm. dgv2 is just one way to work with the data, your program may deal with the data differently.